# Which is more efficient | tag.class or .class-tag?

Tags: html, css

In terms of efficiency and expandability, which of the following lines of code is a better option?

```
tag.class{
}

.class-tag{
}
```

Practical example :

```
button.nav-item{
}

.nav-item-button{
}
```

Although this seems insignificant, I believe it would matter greatly when developing a massive website.

Comment: `button.nav-item`, keeps the html and css shorter and faster to load. You could also just use `.nav-item` and it will apply to all elements with that class. Unless you want to be more specific and apply to only the buttons, use the selector in your example.

Comment: .class-tag would be better since it would apply to all element having that class instead of specific button.class element, read also about css specificity/precedence

Comment: http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/

Comment: The major difference between your two examples is one of specificity. Efficiency will not play a role there.